# Deleted ~/.kube/config

Tags: kubernetes, devops, kubectl, k3s

I accidentally deleted the config file from ~/.kube/config. Every kubectl command fails due to config missing.

Example:

```
kubectl get nodes
```

> The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you
> specify the right host or port?

I have already install k3s using:

```
export K3S_KUBECONFIG_MODE="644"
curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | sh -s - --docker
```

and kubectl using:

```
snap install kubectl --classic
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Do you have /etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml file in your file system?

Comment: No, I do not have.

Comment: Not even in the machine where k3s is running?

Comment: I have installed K3s in my laptop, so I am searching in this machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The master copy is available at /etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml. So, copy it back  to ~/.kube/config

```
cp /etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml ~/.kube/config
```

Reference: https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/cluster-access/

Comment: Thank you, I found it.